# iOS UITableView animating only first visible cell

Tags: ios, animation, uitableview

I want to implement an `UITableView` with some animation while the user is scrolling. Only the first visible (top most) cell has to be an different layout. Before the second cell reaches the top of `UITableView` I want to start the small animation. (changing background alpha and width of cells contentView etc.)

How could I handle this?

[UPDATE]

What I have tried so far:

- using UIScrollView delegate method `scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView` 
  together with UITableView´s `visibleCells` property using the first item of it to get the 
  reference with no luck

Comment: Have you tried something so far?

Answer (score 1):

This is what I have done:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView willDecelerate:(BOOL)decelerate {

     if (!decelerate) {
          [self scrollingFinish];
     }
}
```

..

```
 - (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
     [self scrollingFinish];
}
```

..

```
- (void)scrollingFinish {

    NSIndexPath *firstVisibleIndexPath = [[self.tableView indexPathsForVisibleRows] objectAtIndex:0];

    NSLog(@"first visible cell's section: %i, row: %i", (int) firstVisibleIndexPath.section, (int) firstVisibleIndexPath.row);


    APFCategoryCell * cell = (APFCategoryCell*) [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:firstVisibleIndexPath];

    [cell animateCell];

    [self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:firstVisibleIndexPath atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:YES];

}
```

The problem appears, if the user is scrolling down because the animated cell is still visible and the next one gets animated. So two or more cells are animated. I could going on and implement an method in my custom cell like `- (void) resetAnimatedCell` but maybe there is an much more elegant way for doing this?